# Sampling from weighted sum distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, sampling

I have $n$ probability density functions $p_1, \ldots, p_n$, which I am able to sample from. How to sample from a weighted sum of these PDFs $$c_1 p_1+ \cdots+c_n p_n$$ given that $c_1+ \cdots+c_n=1$? Is is correct to randomly pick one of these PDFs with probability equal to the respective weight and just directly sample the chosen PDF?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. Define a new random variable, $C$, taking values in {1,...n}, such that $\mathbf{P}[C = j] = c_j$. Sample this random variable, and conditioned on $C = j$, sample from distribution $p_j$.

Comment: OK, thanks for confirmation!